# CRISPR Screen Control - What genes do not affect phenotype when knocked out?

Tags: crispr, genetics

I have some raw read count data from a crispr screen.
The library used was addgene's

> Mouse Improved Genome-wide Knockout CRISPR Library v2

I'm following an analysis pipeline that requires counts from **non target gRNA** in my raw read count file.

But the gRNA library does not contain **non target gRNA**.

I'm wondering what genes are commonly used as phenotypic controls in CRISPR screens?

In other words, what `Genes`, when mutated, does not affect the cell's fitness, thus can be used as a reference when comparing gRNA counts?

Comment: I would make this in a data-driven fashion. Check those genes that are canonically not expressed based on RNA-seq data in the cell type that was used here. The respective guides should have no impact and should serve as a proxy for the technical variability of the assay.